# Unable to publish vs code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When trying to publish vs code extension using the vsce tool as so :

```
vsce publish
```

or

```
vsce package
```

I get always the same error :

> Error: Make sure to edit the README.md file before you publish your
>   extension.

Obviously, I have updated the README.md file accordingly to what the extension does. But the error keeps on showing.

This was right after I set up a publisher account and access token with

```
vsce create-publisher (publisher name)
```

I am sure the problem is elsewhere but the error message is not saying what it is.

> Windows 10 64 bits [Window Title] Visual Studio Code
>
> [Main Instruction] Visual Studio Code
>
> [Content]
>
> Version 1.22.2 Commit 3aeede733d9a3098f7b4bdc1f66b63b0f48c1ef9 Date
>   2018-04-12T16:38:45.278Z Shell 1.7.12 Renderer 58.0.3029.110 Node
>   7.9.0 Architecture x64

Did someone come across this error ?

Comment: Maybe something is wrong/missing in the readme file? Maybe it contains some default content yet?

Comment: just remove README string from file and it will fix this

Answer (score 29):

Ok, so the problem was that very first line of the README that says :
"This is the README of your extension "
Although I have made changes all over the file, that line was making the vsce stop the publish process.
Just removed that line and it all worked fine!
Extension is called surround-with for those who want to try it.

Comment: For others reading: vsce package is specifically looking for this "This is the README for your extension " string anywhere in your README.md. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-vsce/blob/0bcfce9172b19c798cc91cbee4dc4398e7455535/src/package.ts#L367